# Evitar depender de una versión en concreto de una libería

Tags: python, c++, qt

El título no es muy descriptivo. A ver si soy capaz de explicarme.

Tengo una aplicación en c++/Qt que hace uso de módulos de python mediante Python/C API.
A la hora de compilar, lo hago usando la versión que tengo instalada en mi ordenador. En este caso (archivo *.pro):

```
unix {
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.6m
    LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib/python3.6 -lpython3.6m
    DEPENDPATH +=  /usr/include/python3.6m
}

win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\Python\Python37\include
    LIBS += -L C:\Python\Python37\libs -lpython37
    DEPENDPATH += C:\Python\Python37\include
}
```

Luego tengo un `pyrun.h` y un  `pyrun.cpp` donde están las funciones propias para leer y ejecutar módulos. En el *.cpp tengo:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "./pyrun.h"
```

La duda la tengo porque al estar compilado con esas versiones de librerías en concreto, al intentar ejecutar la aplicación en otro ordenador me reclama exactamente esas versiones, aún teniendo versiones superiores.
Entonces, ¿ese es el comportamiento normal? ¿Se puede hacer que admita versiones superiores?

Gracias

**Edito:**

Intento añadir datos a la pregunta, que no está muy bien formulada.

Si hago `ldd` a mi aplicación, obtendré las librerías de las que depende:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcf0bbc000)
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007f657385f000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f6573644000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f6573433000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f65731f4000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f6572fa7000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f6572da5000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f6572b7d000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f6572845000)
...
```

Entonces, si por ejemplo se actualizara `libxcb-glx.so.0`, el programa no se quejaría. Pero sin embargo, el hecho de tener una versión de python superior a la que se ha usado para la compilación (en mi caso la 3.6 `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`) ocasiona que el programa reclame la versión exacta.

Comment: Estás enlazando contra `-lpython3.6m`. Te debería funcionar con con cualquier versión: `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`, `libpython3.6m.so.2.0`, `libpython3.6m.so.3.0`, ...

Comment: Lo que no te va a funcionar es con versión de python superiores, tal como `libpython3.8` ¿ Que versión es la que está instalada en ese equipo en el que dices que no funciona ?

Comment: Pues esa era la duda! Pensaba que tendría que funcionar con cualquier versión superior a la 3.6, pero no es así. Solo funciona con versiones superiores de la 3.6. No sabía interpretar los números de versiones. Y claro, el problema era ese, que cualquier persona que me prueba el programa con una 3.8, por ejemplo, me dice que le están obligando a hacer un "downgrade". Pues aclarado!

Comment: Lo correcto sería no dejar la pregunta sin respuesta ... ¿ podrías auto-responderte ? Creo que ya has notado la diferencia entre **el nombre** `libpython3.6m.so` y **la versión** `.1-0` xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuesta está en los comentarios de @Juanjo.

Mi error era pensar que una librería de python superior (3.8 vs 3.6 en mi caso) sería de alguna forma compatible sin más con una aplicación que usa y enlaza a una inferior.

Solamente versiones superiores que usan el mismo número pueden hacer eso (obviamente, por otro lado).

Answer (score 3):

> La duda la tengo porque al estar compilado con esas versiones de librerías en concreto, al intentar ejecutar la aplicación en otro ordenador me reclama exactamente esas versiones, aún teniendo versiones superiores

**Peligros del cambio de versión**

Este problema se da cuando se enlaza con librerías dinámicas.

Una librería dinámica no es más que código binario que no tiene puntos de entrada (la típica función `main`). No es más que una colección de funciones (su API) a disposición de los programas que hagan uso de dicha librería.

Cuando alguien saca una versión nueva de una librería es porque esa nueva versión tiene cambios respecto a la versión anterior. Estos cambios podríamos agruparlos en:

1. Nueva funcionalidad: Se añaden nuevas funciones a las ya disponibles. Estos cambios no afectarán de ninguna manera a tu programa.
2. Cambios internos: se corrigen fallos o se mejoran algoritmos internos. Estos cambios pueden tener impacto en tu programa, al ofrecer resultados diferentes a los obtenidos con la versión anterior.
3. Cambios externos: Se modifica la interfaz de funciones ya disponibles o se eliminan funciones. Este tipo de cambios pueden, directamete, tumbar tu aplicación. Si tu programa hace uso de una función cuya firma es diferente (en vez de un float ahora necesita un string, por ejemplo) o si resulta que la función directamente no existe, se generará un error que impedirá a tu programa funcionar correctamente.

Así pues, el cambio de versión de una librería no es una operación trivial sino que entraña sus riesgos.

**Desarrollo vs despliegue**

Cuando tu estás desarrollando un programa normalmente haces uso de una versión para desarrolladores de la librería. Esta versión se caracteriza por:

- Se encuentra en una ruta conocida por la aplicación (la estás indicando en el .pro)
- Incluye las cabeceras que permiten que tu programa compile y enlace correctamente

Cuando tu despliegas tu aplicación deberías, como norma general, incluir las librerías de las que dependes en el despliegue. Si no lo haces, el programa tiene que encontrar una librería compatible en el sistema

¿Tu has programado esa búsqueda en algún sitio?

Lo normal es que no lo hayas hecho. La consecuencia es que tu programa intentará localizar las librerías en una serie de rutas prefijadas:

- El directorio donde se encuentra el ejecutable
- Rutas incluidas en la variable de entorno de librerías

Si el programa no es capaz de encontrar las librerías en estas rutas no podrá ejecutarse correctamente y finalizará con error.

Comment: Gracias @eferion. Como siempre la explicación clara y concisa. Pero mi duda es....si hago ldd a mi aplicación me saldrán muchas librerías del sistema. Esas librerias se suelen actualizar, y no hay queja por parte del programa en este caso, ¿Por qué sí lo hace en el caso de una librería enlazada de forma explícita?

Comment: @user3733164 porque esas librerías del sistema se encuentran en rutas localizables a través del punto 2 (rutas incluidas en la variable de entorno)

Comment: Hola de nuevo @eferion. Si, eso lo entiendo. Las librerías del sistema están en las rutas que busca el programa por defecto. Pero mi duda es, si hago un ldd a la aplicación, me saldrán las librerías necesarias en un formato tal que así: libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 . Entonces, si esta librería se actualizase, el programa no se quejaría. Pero si en el sistema tuviera una versión superior de python, mi programa me reclama la versión concreta. Voy a actualizar un poco la pregunta. Siento ser tan pesado. :-|